# intuitionistic logic - Brouwer's laws

Tags: logic, intuitionistic-logic

I've been on constant search for any proof regarding the Law of Triple Negation. I happened to find [Brouwer's paper](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=B88L2k5KnkkC&pg=PA12&lpg=PA12&dq=%22absurdity+of+absurdity+of+absurdity%22&source=bl&ots=vWa7jIhcC_&sig=n4fveXqex5D57etqDoOezIYBT5o&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiYnfHst7jSAhXFcBoKHQfhCZsQ6AEIITAB#v=onepage&q=%22absurdity%20of%20absurdity%20of%20absurdity%22&f=false), and he provided a theorem which seemed to be the law of triple negation:
$$
\lnot P \leftrightarrow \lnot \lnot \lnot P
$$

How would one go about translating the theorem and its proof into modern terminology?

Comment: Could you please include more information in the question? I see there was once an image, but it was removed without adding the formula in its place.  It is important to have enough information for the question to make sense to future readers.

Comment: @CarlMummert: Here's a google books link. it's this theorem about what Brouwer called [absurdity of absurdity of absurdity](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=B88L2k5KnkkC&pg=PA12&lpg=PA12&dq=%22absurdity+of+absurdity+of+absurdity%22&source=bl&ots=vWa7jIhcC_&sig=n4fveXqex5D57etqDoOezIYBT5o&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiYnfHst7jSAhXFcBoKHQfhCZsQ6AEIITAB#v=onepage&q=%22absurdity%20of%20absurdity%20of%20absurdity%22&f=false). (Google finds that phrase.)

Comment: @RobArthan so based on the link, how did Brouwer come up with the second part of the proof, that is ¬P → ¬¬¬P? In the book, it does sound like Brouwer is explaining it intuitionistically, but not much was presented in his secondly part compared to his first part other than using a "particular truth"?

Comment: You aren't parsing it right (possibly because it's not very well punctuated), It should be parsed like this: "Truth of an assertion implies [truth of its double negation]. In particular, truth of absurdity implies [truth of the double negation of absurdity]". In symbols, this translates into what I said in my answer about Brouwer's proof (where Brouwer writes "$P$ is absurd", we would write $\lnot P$).

Comment: @RobArthan Ah I see. I know that P does imply the double negation of P, but how does the last part imply that the negation of P implies the triple negation of P? I see that "In particular, negation of P implies triple negation of P". Is that just a fact given the properties of negation or am I missing something?

Comment: Like I said in my answer: if you take $Q = \lnot P$ in $Q \to \lnot\lnot Q$, you're there.

Comment: @RobArthan what is allowing us to perform such substitution? Is it because of what we showed in the "firstly" part that allows us to do substitution without an explanation or?

Comment: The formula $Q \to \lnot\lnot Q$ is valid for all formulas $Q$. In particular it is valid when $Q$ is $\lnot P$ (for any formula $P).

Comment: @M.Alexander:  Perhaps you have clarified your thinking about this Question.  If so, you are welcome to incorporate that clarification into the body of the Question (by Editing).  As it stands the terse Question statement brings up "any proof" and "translating" in connection with the intuitionistic proposition.  It might be ripe for you to restate your Question more clearly after the above exchange of Comments.

Comment: @hardmath: as the question is interesting, but the OP seems to have lost interest $\ddot{\frown}$, I have taken the liberty of editing the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right about what Brouwer is asserting. Here is how I would prove it.

1) Assume $P \to Q$ and $((P \to Q) \to Q)$, then you can conclude $Q$. Discharging the assumptions, you have proved $(P \to Q) \to (((P \to Q) \to Q) \to Q)$.

2) Assume $P$ and $P \to Q$, then you can conclude $Q$. Discharging the assumptions, you have proved $P \to ((P \to Q) \to Q)$.

3) Assume $((P \to Q) \to Q) \to Q$ and $P$. By (2) and the second assumption, you have $(P \to Q) \to Q$ and then by the first assumption you have $Q$. Discharging the assumptions, you have proved $(((P \to Q) \to Q) \to Q) \to (P \to Q)$.

4) By (1) and (3) you have $(P \to Q) \leftrightarrow (((P \to Q) \to Q) \to Q)$. Put $Q = \bot$ (or, if you prefer, $\mathsf{false}$) so that $A \to Q$ is equivalent to $\lnot A$. This gives $\lnot P \leftrightarrow \lnot\lnot\lnot P$.

Note that this doesn't use any special properties of $\bot$. It doesn't require *ex falso quodlibet*.

Here's a comparison with Brouwer's proof as given in your link:

Brouwer's "Firstly" is my (3) which Brouwer proves by observing that $(P \to Q) \to (\lnot Q \to \lnot P)$ and uses the "established fact" that $P \to \lnot\lnot P$ to conclude that $\lnot\lnot\lnot P \to \lnot P$.

Brouwer's "Secondly" is my (1), which Brouwer proves by instantiating $Q$ in $Q \to \lnot\lnot Q$ as $\lnot P$ to conclude $\lnot P \to \lnot\lnot\lnot P$.

As a light-hearted aside: Either Brouwer or the translator of the text in your link is to be "congratulated" ($\ddot{\frown}$) for a fine way to make a proof of an equivalence incomprehensible: "Firstly, blah, blah, blah, so we conclude the implication of $A$ by $B$. Secondly, dudum, dudum, dudum, so $A$ implies $B$.

Comment: What do you mean exactly when you discharge the assumptions? Could you explain?

Comment: [Natural deduction](http://www.iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/): assume $X$, deduce $Y$, then use the rule of implication introduction to conclude $X \to Y$, which discharges the assumption $X$. \\ And can you **please** put the relevant link back in your question so it can be taken off hold.

Comment: While the above scheme of "discharging" assumptions seems compatible with intuitionistic logic,  the phrase "natural deduction" is a bit troubling because of its association with standard logic and proof by contradiction in particular.   I think the Question, should it be reopened, would benefit from a formal intuitionistic proof.

Comment: @hardmath: duh? What "association with standard logic and proof by contradiction" are you talking about? Natural deduction is a well-understood and widely used approach to formalising intuitionistic logic.